# allow_url_fopen and remote files

Tags: php, include, fopen

I am having 3 servers, in where I uploaded my files, the first server I have my codes, and server2 plus server3 contains my files to be downloaded, while being in server1, can we download files in server2 and server3 even though both functions **allow_url_fopen** and **allow_url_include** are OFF?

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: What do you mean? To download files from servers 2 and 3 or to upload files to servers 2 and 3?

Comment: download them from server2 and server3